# How to compute degree of $f: S^1\to S^1$ defined as $e^{ix}\mapsto e^{iax}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, de-rham-cohomology

How to compute degree of $f: S^1\to S^1$ defined as $e^{ix}\mapsto e^{iax}$?

It is known that $f$ induces a vector space isomorphism $H^1(f): \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ which is multiplication by a number that we call degree $(f)$.

The following theorem is also known to me:

If $M,N$ are oriented, compact, connected, $n-$ dimensional manifolds, $f:M\to N$ is smooth map such that $q\in N$ is a regular value of $f$ (i.e., derivative of $f$ is surjective for all $p\in f^{-1}(q)$), then

$a) f^{-1}(q)$ is a finite set. That is, $f^{-1}(q)=\{p_1,...,p_k\}$ for some $p_i\in M$.

$b)$ degree($f)=\sum_i\epsilon(p_i)$, where $\epsilon(p_i)= 1$, if derivative $Df_{p_i}$ preserves orientation; and $\epsilon(p_i)=-1$ otherwise.

I tried the following:

$1)$ If $1$ is a regular value, then $f^{-1}(1)=\{p_1,..., p_k\}$. for $p_i\in S^1$.

$f^{-1}(1)=\{e^{ix}\in S^1: e^{iax}=1\}\implies \cos ax=1,\sin ax=0\implies ax=2n\pi \forall n\in \mathbb Z$.

Case $1:$ Suppose that $a$ is a non integer real number.

$f^{-1}(1)$ is an infinite set. So degree doesn't make sense.

Case $2:$ $a$ is an integer.

In this case, $f^{-1}(1)$ is finite.

$2)$ I don't understand how to calculate $\epsilon(p_i)$'s here: if it were $f(x,y)=(\cos ax, \sin ax)$, then no problem. But it is, $f(e^{ix})= e^{iax}$ so how to compute its differential to know if it is orientation preserving or not, i.e., to know $\epsilon(p_i)$?

Comment: For a rational number $a$ that is not an integer, your attempt faces an enormous obstacle: the formula $e^{ix} \mapsto e^{iax}$ does not give a well-defined function $S^1 \mapsto S^1$.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks. I observed problems for a being irrational: in this case the inverse image of 1 is not finite. But I hadn't checked for a rational but not an integer. So let's suppose a to be an integer (a non zero integer as for a=0 f is not surjective hence degree f =0). I want to know the approach, the idea to compute the degree.

Comment: Let me then suggest that you hit the edit button and correct your attempt.

Comment: @LeeMosher: I'll add some more details in some time. Thanks. I want to learn this stuff. I didn't find any solved examples anywhere so that I could learn this on my own.

Comment: @LeeMosher: Suppose a to be a non zero integer. Then note that if $f(e^{it})= (e^{it})^a=1$, then $e^{it}\in $ {|a|th roots of unity } and hence $f^{-1}(0,1)$ is a set of a elements.
Taking a chart $\phi: (-1,1)\to S^1$ at (0,1) such that $\phi(t)= e^{it}$ and $\psi: f\circ \phi(-1,1)\to (-1,1)$ defined as $\phi(e^{iat})= t$, $\phi\circ f\circ \psi$ is an identity map and hence orientation preserving.
Therefore by the theorem I wrote in my post, deg (f)= a.